# Qual o conceito que envolve as ferramentas/workflow front-end?

Tags: front-end, bower

Pouco tempo depois que comecei a trabalhar nesse ramo eu tive contato com os termos front-end e back-end, mas só nos últimos tempos, eu tive maior contato com as ferramentas para workflow (bower, less, sass, yo, GIT etc).

Só pra explicar melhor a minha necessidade, eu comecei trabalhando numa empresa que desenvolvia sites, mas não era o foco principal, então era bem meia boca, usava o método de:

baixa arquivo do FTP > edita (HTMLs cheio de tables e CSSs desorganizados) > salva > upa para o FTP > atualiza o site > (se funcionou, sucesso, senão, repete os passos até funcionar)

Mas em pouco tempo eu percebi que era uma pratica beeeeem deteriorada, então mudei alguns passos (principalmente para teste localhost), e, por motivos pessoais, ainda não implementei o uso do GIT para versionar.

Mas hoje eu vejo essas ferramentas front-end, como base de exemplo eu vou pegar o Bower.
Qual o conceito de uso do Bower?
No caso, eu crio todo o código front-end, pra no fim eu gerar um resultado (JSs e CSSs concatenados e minificados) para um destino, só então programar? (leia-se programar no sentido de codificar/implementar em um CMS)

Mas e se eu quiser dar manutenção para o mesmo, e tiver mais pessoas trabalhando no mesmo projeto?

Eu estou me equivocando sobre uso?

Eu preciso de uma luz hehe pois tenho sede por utilizar essas ferramentas, principalmente pré-processadores. Penso em iniciar o uso de bootstrap, mas não quero ficar mexendo nos arquivos CSS e sim usar a sintaxe SASS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não entendi bem sua dúvida, mas acho que esta resposta pode te ajudar a achar um caminho.

É legal ter essa sede de conhecer novas tecnologias, mas não precisa sair usando tudo o que está na moda só porque parece que todos usam, que é legal, e que dizem ser "correto" usar. As ferramentas existem para resolver um problema. Se você não tem o problema que elas resolvem, não existe motivo para querer a ferramenta! Para que comprar uma chave de fenda se o que você precisa é serrar uma tábua?

Então você diz que quer usar pré-processadores de CSS, e que até já escolheu o SASS. Ótimo, comece por aí! Estude o SASS e teste, veja como ele funciona. Quer usar isso para personalizar o Bootstrap? Certo, então esse é o próximo passo. Dominando minimamente o SASS, pesquise sobre o Bootstrap e entenda como customizá-lo com esse pré-processador.

Muito bem. Então você tem um projeto usando Bootstrap e SASS, e está trabalhando nele (sozinho ou em equipe, não importa). Abriu no browser, está funcionando. Mas você quer trocar a cor de uma fonte. Você altera o arquivo `.sass` correspondente (seja ele do bootstrap ou outro do seu projeto), executa o SASS para gerar o CSS e recarrega a página. Ótimo, funcionou! Porém, é um pouco repetitivo fazer isso toda vez que for alterar o visual. Se estiver mexendo num sistema em produção, provavelmente é mais trabalhoso ainda, já que pode ser necessário minificar e concatenar todos os CSSs em um só. E olha que nem estamos tratando de JS, só de CSS!

É aí que entram ferramentas para te ajudar no processo. No caso, seria o [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) ou uma ferramenta similar, que serve para automatizar e sequenciar tarefas. Você cria um pacote de instruções, roda um comando, e pronto, todas as tarefas são executadas, na ordem certa pra você, inclusive atualizar o browser e copiar os arquivos finais para o servidor de produção (seja via git, ftp, rsync ou outros métodos).

Sobre o Bower, ele é um gerenciador de pacotes, serve para outra coisa. Não sei se você já usou o npm, que é o gerenciador de pacotes do node.js. O Bower faz a mesma coisa que o npm, mas os pacotes são componentes de front-end, e não módulos do Node (aliás o Bowser requer o Node para funcionar, e é instalado via npm). Ele é útil para projetos em que você usa várias bibliotecas/frameworks ao mesmo tempo, e quer mantê-las sempre atualizadas. Se algum desses componentes depende de outros, o Bower gerencia isso pra você também. Você lista as bibliotecas num arquivo de configuração, e o Bower se encarrega de buscar e baixar/instalar as atualizações quando for executado. Portanto, o bower não serve para concatenar nem minificar JS ou CSS. Existem outras ferramentas para isso. E existe o Grunt e outras ferramentas similares para automatizar o uso desse arsenal todo.

Mas não custa repetir o que eu disse no começo: procure as ferramentas adequadas para resolver cada problema. Enquanto você não tem o problema, não precisa da ferramenta para solucioná-lo! Aprenda as linguagens e ferramentas um passo de cada vez, à medida que cada uma for sendo necessária. Tentar aprender e usar tudo de uma vez só tem grandes chances de te atrapalhar mais do que ajudar.